# Permissions setting for home folder

Tags: ubuntu

What are the best practices in setting permission so that other user can't access my home folder?

They should be able to login, ssh, compile programs etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chmod 700 $HOME` are the safest permissions. This gives no permission at all for group and other; they won't be able to enter your home directory, neither to read its contents or write files into it.

However, it is not clear to me what you mean by

> They should be able to login, ssh, compile programs etc.